# No entry fields preclude the possibility of SQL injections?

Tags: sql, forms

As far as I know, PHP applications are prone to SQL injections when they require user input on a webpage form to send to a variable like $POST or $GET or $REQUEST. Does that mean if my application/htmlpage has no user input forms, it is completely free from SQL injections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ANY user input can cause SQL injections. Say, for example that you perform a SQL query with parameters from the query string. If you haven't sanitized these parameters, you are still prone to SQL injection.

The best thing you can do is to **never trust user input and always sanitize**

To protect against SQL injection *use prepared statements and parameterized queries*

see : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: But how would they directly access the query string?

Comment: Well, that's the easy part, since that is the URL :) `whatever.com/index.php?where=whatever`

Comment: Oh. That makes more sense now. Thanks! I'll accept your answer in a few minutes.